# Django Upload Multiple Files

Tags: django, python-3.x

I want to uplaod multiple files through Django Forms and save the path of uploaded files to the database table. But whenever i'm using this method to uplaod file data is been stored to database but different rows are been created in the database table for each file of multiple upload.

I have tried following method

Multiple files is been uploaded through other_files

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from categories.models import Categories
from .models import Process

class ProcessingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    files = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Categories.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Process
        fields = ('category', 'files', 'lookup_files', 'other_files')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Process(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=CATEGORIES, null=True, 
              blank=True)
    files = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    lookup_files = models.FileField(upload_to='processing/%Y/%m/%d/Lookup', 
    verbose_name=('Lookup File [For Tagging]'), validators=
     [validate_file_extension])
    other_files =models.FileField(upload_to='processing/%Y/%m/%d/other_files', 
    null=True, blank=True)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from categories.models import Categories
from django.contrib import messages
from .models import Process

def process(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProcessingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)        
        # print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            category = form.cleaned_data['category']
            files = form.cleaned_data['files']
            lookup_files = request.FILES['lookup_files']
            other_files =  request.FILES.getlist('other_files')
            print(len(other_files))
            # file_list = []
            for oth in other_files:
                print(oth)
                # file_list.append(oth)
                form = Process(category=category, files=files, 
                       lookup_files=lookup_files, other_files=oth)
                form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'File uploaded succcessfully')
            return redirect('process')
        else:
            print("Form is not valid")
            messages.warning(request, 'File extension is not valid')
            return redirect('process')

    else:
        form = ProcessingForm()
        return render(request, 'process/process.html', {'form':form})
```

Need all these rows in in single rows[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should change your strategy (This will be the best way, imho). You need one more Table just for files and relation between Process table and File table. Use ForeignKey relation for this. You will have one process and many files (OneToMany).

```py
class OtherFile(models.Model):
    other_file = models.FileField(upload_to='processing/%Y/%m/%d/Lookup', verbose_name=('Lookup File [For Tagging]'), validators=[validate_file_extension])
    process = models.ForeignKey(to=Process, on_delete=models.PROTECT) # this is process_id
```

Comment: It didn't help either

Comment: As a mentioned relation is the best way this case,,, Because django's FileField/ImageField does not work in the same fashion as you expected.

Comment: Thank you for Reply Can you please eleborate what you were trying to say before.And i' trying to upload multiple files through other_files field not through lookup_files.

Comment: You need one more model (database table) as I showed you in the example. Name of model will be OtherFile with fields (other_file which is FileField and process which is foreign key to the process table). This will give you opportunity to have relations, between process and otherfile.

Comment: You will avoid duplications.

Comment: How to add fields in forms for other model  `class ProcessingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    files = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Categories.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Process
        fields = ('category', 'files', 'lookup_files', 'other_files') `

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use a Forign Key, join the file names using any separator like `'---' AllLinks = [oth,]` and you can save it in the one row. You have to split the names again using `AllLinks.split('---')` to get the file link when you have to fetch the data.

To avoid this, better is to make forign key relationship.